# KernelBase.dll crash while compiling notepad++ project with MS VS 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, notepad++

I followed first the instructions written in this thread " [How do I build Notepad++ with Visual C++ 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710168/how-to-build-notepad-with-visual-c-2010-express/4984929#4984929) "

Although all the files were compiled successfully when I built notepad++ project on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, yet I get this:

> First-chance exception at 0x7543b727 (KernelBase.dll) in Notepad++.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0020ff80..
>
> First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in Notepad++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x7543b727 (KernelBase.dll) in Notepad++.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Win32AccessViolation at memory location 0x00210388..

Where could the problem be ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling a Debug build of Notepad++? if so they compile fine with the changes, but crash when starting.

Unicode Release builds (after the modifications you linked to) build and run fine (on express and pro, at least).

Comment: I am compiling with a Debug and release builds, yet same results come out!

I tried Unicode Debug build, but the application couldn't launch! I tried Unicode Release build and same crash of DLL occured !

Comment: I'm not sure then, googling for crashes with regards to KernelBase appears to generally be related to driver issues etc.  Have you tried compiling on the Express edition of VS2010? (Express and Ultimate can be installed side by side).