# What headers do I include for swprintf_s and sprintf_s?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When using `swprintf_s` and `sprintf_s` I get the errors below. How can I resolve those?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [per the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) the required headers are

> C++: `<cstdio>`, `<cwchar>`, `<stdio.h>` or `<wchar.h>`

Comment: thanks for the correction, i am actually not using the mentioned functiones, this just pops up in a project when trying to include string so the title is not correct now, your suggestion is not working unfortunately

Comment: @vtz feel free to undo any changes that may have changed your question. I apologize if my edits were wrong. So your real issue is an existing project not compiling? A quick look at those file names point me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710168/how-do-i-build-notepad-with-visual-c-2010-express Is that related to your problem?